# How to select multiple files in different subfolders on Windows?

Tags: windows, forms, filepicker

I can't believe I have to ask this, but the answer will save me from having to write code around this problem.  We have a scientific data submission web form.  Users usually organize their data into subfolders.  When I created the interface, I just added a multi-file select list to the form.  Simple, right?  I was testing on a mac, on which it's extremely easy to select multiple files, even if they are in different subfolders.  You just go to list view and option-click the parent folder to expand all subfolders, then click and command-click to select what files you want.

I have a user on windows who asked me to write code to search subfolders for his data submissions.  I didn't understand what the problem was, so I had him send me a screen recording of what he was doing.  Apparently, the multi-file picker on Windows only shows you one folder at a time (without the ability to expand sub-folders in place)?  And anytime he navigated to another subfolder, it cleared his selections in the previous folder.

I figured that Windows HAD to have a way to do this, so I worked with him to try exploring the file picker's interface.  I've never been a Windows user.  If I ever sit down at a Windows machine, I don't know my way around, so I didn't know how to advise him, so we were just feeling our way around in the dark and couldn't figure it out.

I am attaching the screen recording he sent that shows when he selects files, then goes to a subfolder and back, his first selections are cleared.

Please, how do you select files from multiple subfolders on Windows so that I don't have to re-invent the wheel?  There's got to be a simple solution, right?

[image]

Comment: Oh wait, the gif is truncated... Let me see if I can fix that and edit the post...

Comment: OK. I had to shorten and compress it. Hopefully it still is helpful. Does the user have to hold a modifier key when going into a subfolder (to prevent the selection from being cleared)?